# Number of Ways to Break a Chocolate Bar

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you break a off a rectangular piece of chocolate from a chocolate bar with m x n squares. [We must respect the structure of the chocolate bar, that is break only along horizontal or vertical lines.

Comment: We are to assume only one break in the bar, right? Or can we allow for multiple breaks?

Comment: Nope @daOnlyBG no assumption regarding to that.

Comment: So the rectangle could even come from the middle of the bar, sharing *no* edge with the edges of the bar?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott pretty much can come from anywhere as long as we respect the nature of the breaks

Comment: Okay; that was the interpretation that I had in mind when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: An $m\times n$ bar has $m+1$ division lines in one direction, say horizontally, and $n+1$ in the other. To determine a rectangle, pick two horizontal and two vertical division lines. In how many ways can you do this?

Comment: I'd say $n-1$ break lines, or do you also include virtual break lines at the beginning and end of the bar?

Comment: @Pieter21: You have to include the edges of the bar in order to account for all possible rectangles.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott not sure in how many ways could you explain a bit more.

Comment: @Eduardo: A rectangle is completely determined by its four edges. Once you decide where the two horizontal and the two vertical edges are, you know where the rectangle is. Conversely, if you know the rectangle, you know where its edges are. Thus, there are exactly as many rectangles as there are ways to choose the lines forming its four edges.

Comment: Each smaller rectangle of this bar gives weigh to 2 ver 2 horizontal lines. for the rectangle we can chose all depends if m>n or m<n or m=n.

Comment: @Eduardo: The relative sizes of $m$ and $n$ don’t matter. A $2\times 3$ bar and a $3\times 2$ bar both give rise to $18$ possible rectangles.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i am gonna take a stab and say n+1 chose 2 times m+1 chose 2

Comment: @Eduardo: Good stab: that’s exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

With only one break line, you have $n-1$ + $m-1$ options.

With any number of break lines, you will have to use the method of inclusion/exclusion, and come up with a nice summation formula.

Comment: This answer isn’t useful: the proposed approach is far too complicated (if it can be made to work at all — it isn’t clear just how inclusion/exclusion would apply).

Comment: Please also check the Brian M. Scott answer, since my interpretation of the question may be wrong. Brian's answer handles the case where keeping the complete bar is also rectangular piece. My answer counts complete rectangular partitioning.